# Compare 2 dataframe date columns to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2. I would like to compare the dates row by row (matching on name) between the two. For example, lets look at Jim in row 1 and row 2 of df1. I would like to see if any of the rows in df2 are within 15 days before the date in date1(in df1) for each Jim row. I have the tables below as well as the expected output. Also, the instance column in df2 is just an identifier for each row, so instance 2 of Jim in df2 ends up being the matching row that is within 15 days for row 1 of Jim in df1.

So the steps for row 1 of Jim in df1 would be:

1. See if row 1 in df1 has one or more rows in df2 with the name Jim, if it doesn't, then put 0 in the within15days column for that row (see expected output)
2. Look at date1 of Jim in row 1 of df1 and see if there is a Jim row in df2 with a date2 that is before date1
3. If there is on or more that are before date1, check if there is one that is 15 days before the date1 for row 1 of Jim in df1
4. If there is, then make a separate column in a new dataframe with a 1 or 0 if there isn't.
5. Repeat for each row in df1

Here are the dataframes:

```
DF1
| Name | Test | Date1                  |
| -----| ---- |------------------------|
| Jim  | 1    |   2020-05-10           |
| Jim  | 2    |   2021-06-11           |
| Bob  | 3    |   2019-05-15           |
| Bob  | 4    |   2022-03-10           |

DF2
| Name | Date2      | Instance|
| -----|------------| ------------|
| Jim  | 2020-06-10 | 1           |
| Jim  | 2021-05-05 | 2           |
| Bob  | 2019-04-15 | 1           |
| Bob  | 2022-03-20 | 2           |

Expected Output
| Name | Test | Date1    | Date2          | Within15days| Instance|
| -----| ---- |----------| ---------------|-------------|---------|
| Jim  | 1    |2020-05-10|2020-05-05      |1            |        2|
| Jim  | 2    |2021-06-11|2021-06-10      |1            |        1|
| Bob  | 3    |2019-05-15|2019-04-15      |0            |        1|
| Bob  | 4    |2022-03-10|2022-03-20      |0            |        2|
```

Edit: Assume that there can only be one row that is within15days of a row in DF1

Comment: What if there are more than 1 date with in 15 days period, For e.g. for "2020-05-10" there might be two dates in DF2, "2020-05-05 " & "2020-05-06", how this will affect o/p?

Comment: @Abhishek You can assume there can only be one instance of a row that is within15days of a row in DF1, good catch, added that to the post.

Comment: Also, for BOB, why there are only two rows- is matching happening on YEAR? As "2019-05-15" can also be clubbed with "2022-03-20" with value 0 in column "Within15days"

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The matching is done on the "Name" column. There are two rows of BOB for the sake of the question. You can see in the expected output, the last row is a 0 because the Date2 is after the Date1 for each BOB.

Comment: When matching on Name - One instance of "BOB" from df1 will get a match with 2 Instances of "BOB" in df2, how system will now which instance of BOB will get in front?

Comment: It will look at each match and see if there is one that has a date that is within 15 days of the BOB in df1, if there isn't, it gets a 0.

Comment: Why `Date2` in df2 is different from `Date2` in expected output? for example Jim's dates : `2021-05-05` in df2 and `2020-05-05` in expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your output doesn't match what you have in the input as stated in my comment. But I m going to provide an answer making some corrections in your data. You could use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa) to merge on `Date` columns and `by='Name'`
The `by=Name` is the key here, because you want to match on these before merging and choose `direction=nearest` instead of `backward`.

and then construct `Within15days` column by computing the difference between the `Date` columns

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':['Jim', 'Jim','Bob', 'Bob'],
    'Test':[1,2,3,4],
    'Date1':['2020-05-10', '2021-06-11', '2019-05-15', '2022-03-10']
})
df1['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date1'])
df1.sort_values('Date1', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':['Jim', 'Jim','Bob', 'Bob'],
    'Date2':['2021-06-10', '2020-05-05', '2019-04-15', '2022-03-20'],
    'Instance':[1,2,1,2]
    
})
df2['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date2'])
df2.sort_values('Date2', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='Date1', right_on='Date2', by='Name', direction='nearest')
df['Within15days'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date1'].to_pydatetime()-x['Date2'].to_pydatetime(), axis=1)
df['Within15days'] = df['Within15days'].apply(lambda x: x.days>=0 and x.days<=15 ).astype(int)
```

print(df):

```
  Name  Test      Date1      Date2  Instance  Within15days
0  Bob     3 2019-05-15 2019-04-15         1             0
1  Jim     1 2020-05-10 2020-05-05         2             1
2  Jim     2 2021-06-11 2021-06-10         1             1
3  Bob     4 2022-03-10 2022-03-20         2             0
```

Comment: This works great! I have a follow up question if you are interested in helping with that as well? It would be the process you listed but adding another condition.

Comment: Ok what is the question?